# Android MediaController custom graphics

Tags: android, mediacontroller

Is there a way to "easily" change the graphics of the MediaController to show a "skip ahead 5sec" or "rev 5 sec" (which I have) instead of the ff and rew buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best will be to copy [source code of MediaController](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/MediaController.java) and change layout according to Your needs. Not easy but the best way :)

You can also try get

```
ImageButton mRewButton;
```

by reflection and try to change it but i will not recommend that. Here is how this can be done:

```
try {
    Field field = mediaController.getClass().getDeclaredField("mRewButton");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object value = field.get(mediaController);
    if (value instanceof ImageButton) {
        // do some changes here
        ((ImageButton) value).setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    //handle errors gently
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    //handle errors gently
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just make sure that before that Your controller is initialized. Result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks suseba for the idea, however its giving me a NoSuchFieldException when I try it.  Have to thank of something else.  Don't really want to copy and change the source code when I'm just wanting to change the forward and rev buttons.  I'll keep looking ...

Comment: @justdan0227 no problem. Unfortunately I am 99% sure that those are only 2 possibilities with this class.